# Does anyone know of any cool JQuery plugins to display a profile picture and acompaning text in a box?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

Ive seen a few however they dont seem to allow you to write much text alongside an image, its mostly a brief title or caption display whereas I have quite alot of text that I would like to be displayed alongside an image. preferably in some kind of light box. Id be very grateful if anyone has any suggestions. Im new to Jquery :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at [jQueryUI's Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)? It's quite nice and you can just pump any HTML directly into it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JQuery galleryview for my project. here is the link on the development server. Click on one of the button for example:

http://ssdev01.uis.kent.edu/VotingApplication/Main.aspx